# $2$-Norm for Convolution

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

Let $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ be the following:

$$C_c = \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \mid \exists T > 0 \text{ s.t. } f(t) = 0  \text{ for } |t| \geq T\}$$

Let $T_n \in L(C_c(\mathbb{R}))$ be a linear operator such that:

$$T_n u = \delta_n *u, \forall u \in C_c(\mathbb{R}),$$

where

$$
\delta_n(t)= \begin{cases} 
      n^2(t+1/n) & -1/n \leq t \leq 0 \\
      -n^2(t-1/n) & 0 < t \leq 1/n \\
      0 & \text{elsewhere} 
   \end{cases}
$$

I have to prove that with respect to the 2-norm, the operator $T_n$ has $\|T_n\| = 1.$

I cannot use the Young's convolution inequality directly, but I have to use the properties of the Fourier's transform.

So far, I was trying to do the following:

$$\|\delta_n * u\|_2 = \|\mathfrak{F}(\delta_n * u)\|_2 = \|\mathfrak{F}(\delta_n ) \mathfrak{F}(u)\|_2 $$

But then I was wondering how to proceed.

Comment: See my edits to this question for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: Not sure whether it helps but do you know what the Fourier transform of $\delta_n$ looks like?

Comment: @JonasLenz I am trying to compute it. Since $\delta_n$ is a function such that it's limit for n that goes to $\infty$ is the dirac delta function, I was expecting its Fourier to be 1, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: This is what I was expecting too. Does it at least behave like some constant?  Depending on your definition of the Fourier transform there might also be a constant missing when changing the convolution to the product.

Comment: mmmm no, it doesn't.

Comment: @JonasLenz Actually, today I checked my computations and I got the following:
$\mathfrak{F}(\delta_n)(\omega)$  = $(2n/\omega^2)(1-cos(\omega/n))$

Comment: So now I have the following: 
$||\mathfrak{F}(\delta_n)\mathfrak{F}(u)||_2 = ||(2n^2/\omega^2)(1-cos(\omega/n))\mathfrak{F}(u)||_2$